# Checkbox in flutter with maestro

Tags: flutter, testing, maestro

i would like to manage a checkbox in flutter with Maestro Mobile Dev (https://maestro.mobile.dev/) but maestro doesn't identify my widget

```
CheckboxListTile(
   title: Text('localizations.welcomeDisclaimerChoice'),
   value: checkedValue,
   onChanged: (newValue) {
      setState(() {
          checkedValue = newValue!;
      });
   },
);
```

i don't find semantic way to resolve my issue
Any help

Thx

Comment: i have just to tapOn the label...
```MaterialApp(
        showSemanticsDebugger: true,
```

helps me to understand

Comment: Have you tried maestro studio? try adding Semantics to a widget that doesn't have a semanticsLabel and see in maestro studio until the text of the widget is read

Comment: I stopped to try to use Maestro. I prefer to use Patrol